# Constructor <ClassAdapter> na <ClassAdapter> não pode ser aplicado a determinados tipos

Tags: java

Estou tentando implementar um `Searchview` próximo a `Recyclerview` para fazer a filtragem de registros de livros ocorrer. Estou tendo problemas na seguinte linha do arquivo `ListDonos.java`:

Linha:

```
recyclerAdapter = new DonoAdapter();
```

O erro desta linha é:

**error: constructor DonoAdapter in class DonoAdapter cannot be applied to given types; required: `List<Dono>`,Context found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.**

- Arquivo `ListarDonos.java`

```
public class ListarDonos extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DonoAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_donos);
        setTitle("Listar donos");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        Conexao conexao = new Conexao(this);
        List<Dono> donos = conexao.ReadDonos();
        
        if (donos.size() > 0){
            DonoAdapter donoadapter = new DonoAdapter(donos,ListarDonos.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(donoadapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Não existem donos no banco de dados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pesquisar_dono,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.buscar_dono);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                recyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

- Arquivo `DonoAdapter.java`

```
public class DonoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DonoAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Dono> donos;
    List<Dono> donos2;
    Context context;
    Conexao conexao;

    public DonoAdapter(List<Dono> donos, Context context) {
        this.donos = donos;
        this.donos2 = new ArrayList<>(donos);
        this.context = context;
        conexao = new Conexao(context);
    }
    // Método para obter o filtro
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    // Realiza a filtragem
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            List<Dono> filtro_donos = new ArrayList<>();
            if (charSequence.toString().isEmpty()){
                filtro_donos.addAll(donos2);
            } else {
                for (Dono doninho: donos2){
                    if (doninho.getNome_dono().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        filtro_donos.add(doninho);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filtro_donos;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            donos.clear();
            donos.addAll((Collection<? extends Dono>) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Sua classe `DonoAdapter` só tem um construtor e ele  precisa de dois argumentos.

Comment: @EmersonPardo é nesse construtor que eu me perdi.

Comment: Vocẽ precisa fazer a chamada assim: `recyclerAdapter = new DonoAdapter(listaDonos, context);`

Comment: ```listaDonos``` vem de onde?

Comment: O código é seu ,em algum ponto você precisa criar uma instância de uma `List<Dono>` para passar no construtor do `DonoAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe `DonoAdapter` estende `RecyclerView.Adapter` mas na linha que dá erro:

```
recyclerView.getFilter().filter(newText); // ERROR: Cannot resolv method 'getFilter()
```

é chamado o `getFilter` do `RecyclerView` que, pelo texto da mensagem de erro, não tem o método `getFilter()`.

Consultando a [documentação do RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) vê-se que a classe `RecyclerView.Adapter` não tem o método filter. Você precisará fazer um cast para chamar `DonoAdapter.filter()` que é um método exclusivo do seu adapter. Algo como:

```
 DonoAdapter donoAdapter = (DonoAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter();
 donoAdapter.filter(newText);
```

Comment: Não entendi, tentei mudar aqui e não resolveu.

Comment: Tentou mudar esta linha `recyclerView.getFilter().filter(newText);` para ficar assim: `recyclerView.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);`? Deu o mesmo erro?

Comment: Mudei para ```recyclerView.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);``` e deu o erro ```Cannot resolv method 'getFilter()'```

Comment: A classe `RecyclerView.Adapter` não tem o método `filter`. Você precisará fazer um cast para chamar o filtro. Algo como `DonoAdapter donoAdapter = (DonoAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter(); ` e então chamar o filter: `donoAdapter.filter(newText)`

Comment: Pode reformular sua resposta?

Comment: Editei para incluir a resposta com o cast.

Comment: Agora entendi, não retornou nenhum erro, vou fazer o teste aqui e já volto para te responder.

Comment: Ok, se houver novo erro e vocẽ avaliar que não tem relação com este, marque esta como resolvida para que outros saibam qual foi a solução e abra uma outra pergunta com o novo erro. Se o erro ainda tiver relação com este, edite sua questão com a tentativa de solução e o novo erro.

Comment: Fui fazer os testes e o app sempre para de executar quando vou na página de listagem

Comment: Não funcionou Emerson.

Comment: Consegue mais informações sobre o erro pra atualizar sua pergunta?

Comment: Não sei dizer, o compilador não acusa um erro grave.

Comment: Retornei o trecho ao que era antes.